# Error con promesa y ciclo for

Tags: javascript, loops, promesas

Estoy iniciándome con Javascript y aún no manejo bien el tema asíncrono, promesas...etc

La cuestión es, que dentro de un callback necesito acceder a los datos de un array (recorrerlo mediante un for) y esto me lanza un error que no sé como arreglar.

Mi código:

```
var objetoQueGuardo = {'event': 'evento1', 'label': 'valor'};
var dataLayer = [];
dataLayer.push(objetoQueGuardo);

factura.createFactura(id, false, token)
                .then(function successCallback(response) {

            for (var i = 0; dataLayer.length; i++) {
                dataLayer[i].label;
            }

}, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.warn(response);
});
```

He acortado un poco el código, para que ejemplo sea más simple.
El contenido de dataLayer es un array de objetos y me quiero quedar con el atributo label de cada uno.

El error que me muestra:

```
 TypeError: dataLayer[i] is undefined
 Traza de la pila:
    successCallback@http://api.local/components/api/assets/js/factura.js:150:7
    h/<@http://api.local/components/api/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:135:278
    $digest@http://api.local/components/api/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:146:238
    $apply@http://api.local/components/api/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:149:464

 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}
```

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que es `dataLayer[i].label`? Si fuera una función, para invocarla harías `dataLayer[i].label();`. Si fuera un atributo/variable, lo usarías para algo `alert(dataLayer[i].label);`. Y, aunque se agradece el esfuerzo por hacer el código conciso, deberías mostrar dónde y cuando se asignan los valores a `dataLayer[i]` porque parece muy relevante para la pregunta.

Comment: No es una función, es un atributo del objeto que guardo en el array. Ya lo he indicado en el texto antes de indicar el error, gracias

Comment: No te vale hacer un forEach() ??
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu problema es la condición del bucle for:

```
for (var i = 0; dataLayer.length; i++) {
    dataLayer[i].label; // En este ejemplo esta sentencia realmente no hace nada, pero sirve para detectar el error
}
```

es equivalente a escribir

```
for (var i = 0; !!(dataLayer.length); i++) { // !!1 === true
    dataLayer[i].label;
}
```

puesto que `dataLayer.length` es 1, siempre se calcula `true`. Lo que necesitas es comparar la longitud con tu índice:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataLayer.length; i++) {
    dataLayer[i].label;
}
```

Por cierto, lo de dar nombre a las funciones de callback es una buena práctica porque ayuda a depurar errores, como has visto aparece en el "stacktrace" del mensaje de error.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, pensé que era error con la promesa y tenía mal escrita la condición del bucle for... Jo mil gracias!! a veces una se ciega y no ve el error